# Adding interaction terms to step AIC in R

Tags: r

So I have a bunch of variables sitting in a data frame and I want to use the step function to select a model.

Right now I'm doing something like this

```
step(lm(SalePrice ~ Gr.Liv.Area + Total.Bsmt.SF + Garage.Area + Lot.Area, list= ~upper(Neighborhood + Neighborhood:Bedroom.AbvGr) ....
```

How do I add multiple interaction terms without having to manually input them with the : notation?

Comment: `a * b` is equivalent to `a + b + a:b`

Comment: ok but what if I have a, b , c and I want all the interaction terms between them?

Comment: `a * b * c` gives all the interactions.

Comment: so it'll do a + b + c + a:b + a:c + c:b ?

Comment: also, will the variables in the initial model be considered as part of list = ~upper?

Comment: `a * b * c = a + b + c + a:b + a:c + c:b + a:b:c`

Comment: Your `scope` should be a list containing `upper` and `lower` which are also formulas but you can use the `?update` syntax, i.e., `scope = list(lower = . ~ 1, upper = . ~ . + x)` which means that the smallest model you consider is the null model and the largest is the base model plus an additional term, `x`

Comment: @rawr: Maybe you should put in an answer?

Answer (score 14):

Here is one way of adding interactions: Assume that all your data of interest is in `dat` and your dependent variable is named `y`. The code

```
init_mod <- lm(y ~ ., data = dat)
step(init_mod, scope = . ~ .^2, direction = 'forward')
```

will add interaction terms to your model using AIC. If you want *k* order interactions you can replace `.^2` with `.^k`.